# How do I save an edited mesh in MESHLab?

Tags: meshlab

I import a mesh(obj) into a project and edit it... when I save my project and reopen the project, my mesh is still the import mesh. Where is my mistake?

greetings
iom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  menu. Chose: `File / Export Mesh` or  `File / Export Mesh As`. See the Meshlab tutorial http://www.heritagedoc.pt/doc/Meshlab_Tutorial_iitd.pdf

> A project is nothing more than an information structure. It doesn’t contain the point clouds itself.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you export it as a .obj file, you need to include the .mtl and any texture files in the same folder. Otherwise you'll get an untextured/no color object